# Setting title for multiple instances of a parameterised route page

Tags: aurelia

I define a route config as:

```
{ route: 'page/:id', name: 'page', moduleId: 'page', title: "Page #" }
```

I've also got another component listening to the `router:navigation:complete` event (EventAggregator), and, when a different fragment is spotted, it adds it to an array and displays this on the screen (as a sort of History list) using `NavigationInstruction.config.navModel.title`

When I navigate to the 'page' component with different ids time, e.g. `#/page/1`, `#/page/2`, `#/page/3`. I call `NavigationInstruction.config.navModel.setTitle("Page " + id)` from the `activate()` method.

In my history, I initially will see:

```
"Page 1"`
```

... then when navigating to `#/page/2`...

```
"Page 2"
"Page 2"
```

... then when navigating to `#/page/3`...

```
"Page 3"
"Page 3"
"Page 3"
```

Because the `RouteConfig` is shared between the different `NavigationInstructions`, changing the `navModel.title` value affects ALL `NavigationInstructions` derived from that `RouteConfig`.

Anyone got any ideas how I can set a custom title for each instance of the Page component? Is Aurelia expected to deal ok with multiple simultaneous instances of the same component?

I've considered using the new `router.transformTitle` hook, but as I'm likely to eventually include more information in the title, e.g. `"Page 1: Contents"`, `"Page 2: The First Chapter"`, that feels sub-optimal and likely to leave me doing a lot of rolling-my-own architecture to dynamically resolve the string.

Comment: Is it possible that you subscribe to the event aggregator in different VMs but forget to unsubscribe when leaving them?

Comment: No, the VM where I've subscribed to the router:navigation:complete is persistent for the lifetime of the app. So this isn't a multi-call problem, it's just that the Router gets the title from a RouteConfig object which is shared between all NavigationInstructions generated against it.

Answer (score 1):

I created a very simple app to test this. I did use a slightly different strategy though. I used the `activate` callback on the `page` viewmodel instead of subscribing to the `router:navigation:complete` event.
Here's my code:

```
export class Page {
  activate(params, route, instruction) {
    this.pageNumber = parseInt( params.id || '1' );
    instruction.config.navModel.setTitle("Page " + this.pageNumber)
  }
}
```

I'm not seeing the behavior you are seeing:

[image: History Screenshot]

What version of the framework module are you working with?

Comment: Not sure that's testing the same scenario. In that one, you only have one NavigationInstruction at a time, and just update the NavModel each time that you visit any of those pages in the history (before you call the .setTitle, it will be set to the value set in the previous page that you'd navigated to).

Comment: You may have hinted at a solution though. I'll probably have to work around this by only storing or updating the title on navigation:router:complete, rather than referencing the NavigationInstruction directly-  which rather seems only to be intended to have a lifetime that's linked to the particular navigation operation, rather than the fragment in question.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you.

Comment: The example is different. In your scenario, the title is in the Browser's history not in the SPA context, so calls to setTitle won't modify those. When you navigate back to a page, you call setTitle in activate, so it resets there and then.

My example had multiple NavigationInstructions being persisted, and I'm starting to realise that that's probably not an intended usage of that class: NavigationInstruction is expected to largely go out of scope after navigation:router;complete fires, it's not expected to be (as I was using it) a reference to .fragment plus .params.

Comment: Yeah, the instruction represents just that: It's an instruction the router is trying to follow. "Navigate to this route."

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the code, and responses (thanks @Ashley Grant), it appears that my expectations of `NavigationInstruction` were not accurate.

**A `NavigationInstruction` represents a single workflow of triggering, navigation, deactivating previous pages, and activating new pages, and firing any events triggered as part of that process.**

It does not - as I'd thought - represent a 'instance' of a RouteConfig (i.e. the fragment, plus params). Therefore, referring to a `NavigationInstruction` after the `navigation:router:complete` event has fired is not intended, therefore doesn't work!

I'll now rewrite my code to take a copy of the title when the `navigation:router:complete` event fires (this is actually non-trivial, requires calling the `_buildTitle()` private method on the instruction) - and have a raised a FR - https://github.com/aurelia/router/issues/469 - to request that this operation be made less opaque.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for... but in my case the app component's constructor calls a private function to set 'DeepTitle' which basically append's the orginization's name after the page title. However now I have the added overhead of communicating from my component to the app component to set the final title. However thanks @Rick Barber for a informative explination on  NavigationInstruction. Much appreciated !!!